# PowerMock complains of incorrect arguments even though the private method is mocked

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, easymock

I was trying out PowerMock, and am trying to mock a private method like so:

```
expectPrivate(n, "doLogin", anyString(), anyString()).andReturn(true);
```

That is, I want `true` to be returned from `doLogin` irrespective of the parameters passed.
The public method which delegates to this private method simply passes-on the arguments. Here is the definition of the class to be mocked:

```
class N {
        public boolean login(String username, String password) {
            return doLogin(username, password);
        }
        private boolean doLogin(String u, String p){
            //validate login
            //...
            //...
            return true;
        }
     }
```

And this is the test class where I am trying to invoke the mock:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.createPartialMock;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.expectPrivate;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.replay;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verify;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(N.class)
public class NodeAccessorTest {
private String username = "admin";
private String password = "asdf";

@Test
public void testMockLogin() throws Exception {
    N n = createPartialMock(N.class,
            "doLogin", String.class, String.class);
    boolean expected = true;
    expectPrivate(n, "doLogin", anyString(), anyString()).andReturn(expected);
    replay(n);
    boolean actual = n.login("A", "B");
    verify(n);
    assertEquals("Expected and actual did not match", expected, actual);
   }
}
```

This is the failure trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call N.doLogin("A", "B"):
    N.doLogin("", ""): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.invoke(EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.java:91)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:124)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:185)
    at com.pugmarx.mock.N.doLogin(N.java)
    at com.pugmarx.mock.N.login(N.java:60)
```

So the mocking framework is not happy when specific `String`s are passed to the `public login()` method, but fine when `anyString` is used. Ideally, I would expect that since the call to the `private doLogin` is mocked, this should not be the case.
What am I missing?

Comment: @Pratik, I have updated the question with it

Comment: Can you post your entire test class if thats not an issue? I can't see any problem here

Comment: @Pratik, No problem, updated again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I think your problem can be in the Matchers `anyString()` passed by param to PowerMock `expectPrivate` method.

Based in your imports, you are using `Mockito` Matchers instead `EasyMock` Matchers: `org.mockito.Matchers.anyString`.

Could you try to changing the Matchers for the next: `EasyMock.anyString()`

```
import org.easymock.EasyMock;

...

expectPrivate(n, "doLogin", EasyMock.anyString(), EasyMock.anyString()).andReturn(expected);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Although I do not understand why.

Comment: This link compares the two (Mockito v/s EasyMock), and claims that the matchers are the same. https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockitoVSEasyMock

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the why...I also supposed we could use Mockito Matchers. Even I thought it was a bug. Anyway, glad to help you!

Comment: So the only difference I could find is that EasyMock.anyString() returns a null, as against the anyString() of Mockito, which returns a blank ("").